# TSQL - Return top 10 customers for each day

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, greatest-n-per-group

SQL Server 2014

I have a table containing the following: -

```
[id ] [transaction_date]                  [customer_id]
 1     2019-11-18 00:00:00.000              1234
 2     2019-11-18 00:00:00.000              1234
 3     2019-11-18 00:00:00.000              5687
 4     2019-11-19 00:00:00.000              9999
 5     2019-11-19 00:00:00.000              8888
...
```

A customer can have multiple transactions on a single day.

I need to return the top 10 customers (based on number of transactions) for each day since the 01/09/2019. e.g customer 1234 made 2 transactions on the 18/11/2019.

How would I go about this?

I started with an initial query of : -

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as transactions, customer_id, DATEADD(DAY,0, DATEDIFF(day,0, transaction_date)) as 'transaction_date' 
FROM  InvoiceTable
WHERE transaction_date > {ts '2019-09-01 00:00:00'}
GROUP BY customer_id, DATEADD(DAY,0, DATEDIFF(DAY,0, transaction_date))
ORDER BY transaction_date
```

But not made much more progress after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract the date, use a conversion to `date`.  The `dateadd()` method has been obsolete for over a decade.

You can combine window functions and aggregation, so the query can look like:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT CONVERT(DATE, transaction_date) as transaction_date, customer_id,
             COUNT(*) as transactions,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CONVERT(DATE, transaction_date) ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM InvoiceTable
      WHERE transaction_date > {ts '2019-09-01 00:00:00'}
      GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE, transaction_date), customer_id
     ) t
WHERE seqnum <= 10
ORDER BY transaction_date;
```

Note that this always returns 10 rows (if there are 10 customers on each day).  If there are ties, then arbitrary tied customers are returned and which customers are returned might vary on different runs of the query.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn your existing query to a subquery, and then use window function `RANK()` to rank the customers by daily transactions for each day, and then filter on the top 10 customers per group:

```
SELECT transactions, customer_id, transaction_date
FROM (
    SELECT
        t.*,
        RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY transaction_date ORDER BY transactions DESC) rn
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            COUNT(*) as transactions, 
            customer_id, 
            DATEADD(DAY,0, DATEDIFF(day,0, transaction_date)) as transaction_date
        FROM  InvoiceTable
        WHERE transaction_date > {ts '2019-09-01 00:00:00'}
        GROUP BY 
            customer_id, 
            DATEADD(DAY,0, DATEDIFF(DAY,0, transaction_date))
    ) t
) t
WHERE rn <= 10
ORDER BY transaction_date, transactions desc
```

Side note: SQL Server is quite flexible about mixing aggregation and window functions, so this *might* work as well:

```
SELECT transactions, customer_id, transaction_date
FROM (
    SELECT 
        COUNT(*) as transactions, 
        customer_id, 
        DATEADD(DAY,0, DATEDIFF(day,0, transaction_date)) as transaction_date,
        RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY transaction_date ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) rn
    FROM  InvoiceTable
    WHERE transaction_date > {ts '2019-09-01 00:00:00'}
    GROUP BY 
        customer_id, 
        DATEADD(DAY,0, DATEDIFF(DAY,0, transaction_date))
) t
WHERE rn <= 10
ORDER BY transaction_date, transactions desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()`

```
with cte as
(SELECT COUNT(*) as transactions, customer_id, DATEADD(DAY,0, DATEDIFF(day,0, transaction_date)) as 'transaction_date',
FROM  InvoiceTable
WHERE transaction_date > {ts '2019-09-01 00:00:00'}
GROUP BY customer_id, DATEADD(DAY,0, DATEDIFF(DAY,0, transaction_date))
ORDER BY transaction_date
)
select * from
(
select *,row_number() over(partition by transaction_date order by transactions desc) as rn from cte
)A where rn<11
```